# How to read output of Sqlcommand in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm fetching date from the database and following is my command for it:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select dob from sample Where cardnum = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'");
```

How do i save the output of this command into datetime?

Comment: You go and read a tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: SqlDataReader is what you want, probably. But First use a parameterised query. SQL Injection attack and passing dates as strings in out of sql server is simply a really bad idea.

Comment: SQL injection. First thing you should learn about.

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest:

```
var when = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

However, in the more general case you woulnd need to know about readers and parameters. Or: use a tool like dapper:

```
var when = conn.Query<DateTime>(
    "select dob from sample Where cardnum = @num",
    new { num = TextBox1.Text } // parameters, done right
).Single();
```

But dapper will read entire objects too (mapping properties to columns), not just single values.